# puppeteer wont go to chrome://version when headless mode is true

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation, puppeteer, user-agent

so am using puppeteer.connect method    and am trying to goto chrome://version to extract the user-agent that is being used by puppeteer , so when the headless mode is false it would do fine but when trying headless mode it would give this error

```
 Error: net::ERR_INVALID_URL at chrome://version
```

Code example :

```
 browser = await puppeteer.connect({ browserURL, defaultViewport: null });
 page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto('chrome://version');
  const useragent = await page.waitForSelector('#useragent');
  const UserAgent = await page.evaluate(element => element.innerText, useragent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because Chrome specifically blocks local file access this way for security reasons.

Anyway, you don't need to open the version page to get a user agent. Because there is a method for it:

```js
await browser.userAgent();
```

It returns: `<Promise<string>>` Promise which resolves to the browser's original user agent.